# How to make a resumable upload with Google Drive iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, resume-upload

I am able to upload a file with google drive iOS sdk now. 
Basically using "GTLService executeQuery". 
I get this from [the Google Drive iOS sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart)

But it is not a resumable upload. If the network fail when I upload a big file, the upload will start again from the beginning.

I know how to make a resumable upload with [this method](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)
But can I make a resumable upload with google drive iOS sdk? 
It seems that I can only make it happen with NSURLConnection.

Comment: Please can you share your code to upload image on google drive?